# Create pdf from external template over PHP

Tags: php, templates, pdf, qr-code, barcode

I am search solution for create pdf from external template.
Final pdf will contain graphic files (logo), lines, pictograms, texts, barcode, qr-code, datamatrix code (single page, size to 100 x 100 mm).

Texts, barcode, qr-code will be generated dynamically. But texts will have an exact description (size, position, font, size font, alignment, wrapping, etc.) And place to insert barcode will be specified too.The whole thing will not only work with one template but many!

First question: what to use as a template? (SVG, pdf, ...)

But the basic requirement is that the template can be created super-fast over external program, not that it will create over programing code in PHP or over html/PHP code.

Second question: Which library to use for loading the template, filling template and rendering the pdf file in PHP.

My idea is that I will just replace the text items and add to template barcode and qr-code. The system must be able to generate both 2 D and 3 D codes insert them into the template.

Thank you for the answers

Jaroslav

Answer (score -1):

I've used https://mpdf.github.io/ in past and didn't have too much problems with it. You can use it from PHP and it has ability to generate PDF out of HTML + CSS code. Though you will get less features than in native browsers.

> But the basic requirement is that the template can be created super-fast over external program, not that it will create over programing code in PHP or over html/PHP code.

For this you probably could just deploy multiple web services that generate pdf files.

Comment: mPDF does not solve the situation at all. First, it does not directly support barcode and qr-code generation. Secondly, I don't know of any WYSIWYG editor for creating a simple html + css that works with a millimeter ruler so that every element on the page can be easily and quickly positioned absolutely. The resulting pdf will only be printed, and each element must have the exact size and position.

Comment: Save barcode as image/svg and print it on pdf via <img> tag? And optimize milimiters you need via trial and error?